# How to do IF ELSE in template file for TemplatePower

Tags: variables, if-statement, template-engine

Had to work with a project that uses [**TemplatePower**](http://templatepower.codocad.com/).

My question is: how do I do an `IF ELSE` statement in the **template file *(.tpl)*** to check things like **variable existence** or **output result**?

I had searched but to no avail. I also had suspected it was like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and tried `{if $variable}{/if}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do something like that in your .tpl file. The only way to do something like that is create blocks like:

```
<!-- START BLOCK : user_logged_in -->
  <p>Welcome {username}!</p>
<!-- END BLOCK : user_logged_in -->
<!-- START BLOCK : user_not_logged_in -->
  <a href="login.php">Please click here to log in.</a>
<!-- END BLOCK : user_not_logged_in -->
```

From your PHP code you can then do:

```
if( $user->is_logged_in() )
  $Tpl->newBlock( 'user_logged_in' );
else
  $Tpl->newBlock( 'user_not_logged_in' );
```

Obviously, this is a personal opinion, but I would highly recommend trying to refactor your code to something like Twig or Smarty.

In my company, TemplatePower is used quite heaviliy, but the license costs for TemplatePower combined with the limited possibilities and the last release date are in my opinion reason enough to refactor as much as I can to Twig or Smarty.

Comment: I see. I agree in regards to refactoring but, unfortunately, I do not have that privilege. Just a task given. Thank you for the info & the workaround.